# Determine the degree of the extension over Q

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Determine the degree of the extension $Q(\sqrt{3+2 \sqrt{2}})$ over Q.
I can see that $$3+2 \sqrt{2} = (1+ \sqrt2)(1+ \sqrt2) =(1+ \sqrt2)^2$$ does that mean $$x^2 -(1+ \sqrt2)^2)$$ has a degree $2$. Is this correct

Comment: You have to find an irreducible polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that it has $\sqrt{3+2(\sqrt{2})}$ as a root. Is your polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Comment: yes the polynomial is in $Q[x]$

Comment: what polynomial is of degree $2$? What polynomial is in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?? Write clearly..

Comment: but $(1+ \sqrt{2})^2 = 3 + 2\sqrt{2}$ and this doesnt lie in $\mathbb{Q}$!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193317/degree-of-the-extension-mathbbq-sqrta-sqrtb-over-mathbbq?rq=1 may be of some use..

Answer (score 1):

Example: Let $p(x) = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$.

Let $u = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}} \Rightarrow u^2 = (1+\sqrt{2})^2 = 2+2\sqrt{2} \Rightarrow (u^2-2)^2 = 8 \Rightarrow u^4-4u^2+4=8 \Rightarrow u^4-4u2-4=0$

Hence $u$ is the root of $x^4-4u^2-4$. Try this techniques with your adjoined root and see if you can say anything about the polynomial that it satisifies over $\mathbb{Q}$.