# Use Galois Theory to prove the existence of $A$ and $B$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6+3\sqrt{3}})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{A}, \sqrt{B})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

> Use Galois Theory to prove the existence of $A$ and $B$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6+3\sqrt{3}})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{A}, \sqrt{B})$

So $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6+3\sqrt{3}})$ is the field of rational numbers with the extra element generated by $\sqrt{6+3\sqrt{3}}$. Is this correct? How could we proceed using Galois Theory?

> Find these $A$ and $B$

From inspection I think, without loss of generality, $A=\sqrt{2}$ and $B=\sqrt{3}$.

How could I prove this?

---

Edit, linked question gives useful approach but further answers are welcome (and useful)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Degree of the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193317/degree-of-the-extension-mathbbq-sqrta-sqrtb-over-mathbbq); for $a=6$ and $b=27$.

Comment: Its a different question though. Unless the proof requires calculating the degree, is this the case?

Comment: The answer at the duplicate gives $m$ and $n$ such that the biquadratic extension is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n},\sqrt{m})$ - that's what you want.

Comment: ok thanks I will check it out. I still would like this question open since the answer below for example is helpful

Comment: Sure. And this answer will stay, even if the question were closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @amiz9, something worth noting is that $A$, $B$ are not unique in the slightest, (In fact, you could look up the primitive element theorem, which says you don't even need $B$ as $\mathbb{Q}$ is char $0$). So you shouldn't say "Find **these** $A$, $B$,". You should say "Find **a** pair $A$, $B$".

Answer (score 3):

Notice your element satisfies

> $$(x^2-6)^2-27=0\iff x^4-12x^2+9=0$$

Then if you adjoin the square root of $3$ you get it to split as

$$x^2-6=3\sqrt3$$

i.e. the degree of the total extension is $4$, so the Galois group has order $4$. But there are only two groups of order $4$, and since you can exhibit more than one element of order $2$, you know the Galois group is the Klein $4$ group. But then all such extensions with that Galois group are of the form $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{A},\sqrt{B})$, completing the proof.

Comment: thank you, makes sense. The only thing is how would I know that the Klein 4 Galois group has the form $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{A}, \sqrt{B})$?

Comment: @amiz9 The Klein 4 group has a  normal subgroup of index 2, hence there is an intermediate field of degree 2, which must be of the form $\Bbb Q(\sqrt A)$. As there are three such normal subgroups, we also get $\Bbb Q(\sqrt B)$ and $\Bbb Q(\sqrt C)$. Can you see why the big field is $\Bbb Q(\sqrt A,\sqrt B,\sqrt C)$ and why one of the square roots can be dropped?

Comment: @amiz9 the Galois theory shows that subfields correspond to subgroups. Since the only other finite group of order $4$ has only one proper, non-trivial subgroup, showing multiple ones reduces to the Klein $4$ group case, which is the case you're seeking.