# Degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{7}})$ and splitting field

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory, extension-field

I have two questions:

> Determine the degree of the extension degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{7}})$ over $\Bbb Q$ and the degree of the splitting field of the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{7}}$ over $\Bbb Q$.

For the first one, that's what I have thought:

$$x =\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{7}} \implies x^2 = 2 + \sqrt7 \implies x^4 - 4x^2 -3 = 0$$

Now $m_{a}(x) = x^4 - 4x^2 - 3$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$ and it is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{7}}$, so the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ should be $4$. Am I correct?

About the second question: how can I find the degree of the splitting field of $m_{a}(x)$? The only thing I know is that $m_{a}(x)$ has $4$ roots, which are $\pm\sqrt{2 \pm \sqrt{7}}$. What now?

Comment: Answer: yes, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193317/degree-of-the-extension-mathbbq-sqrta-sqrtb-over-mathbbq). For the splitting field see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204709/computing-the-galois-group-of-x4ax2b-in-mathbbqx), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093107/consider-the-splitting-field-k-of-x4-2x2-2-on-mathbb-q-find-k-mathb).