# Normal extension of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\alpha=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$.

Let $L=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

> Show that $L$ is a normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

I know that we need to prove that the Galois group for this extension is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z_2}$ (which i dont know how to prove ). An extension is normal if and only if the subgroup of automorphisms which fix each intermediate field is a normal subgroup of the Galois group. When this group is abelian, every subgroup is normal and thus every extension is Galois.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We know already that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$ is a biquadratic field, because $2^2-3=1$ is a square:

[Proving $\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}=\sqrt{m}+\sqrt{n}\iff a^{2}-b$ is a square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193276/proving-sqrta-sqrtb-sqrtm-sqrtn-iff-a2-b-is-a-square?noredirect=1&lq=1)

These biquadratic fields are Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$, because they are  separable (the field has characteristic zero) and normal (the roots of  $(x^2-m)(x^2-n)$ are again in the field).

Edit: Here is actually a duplicate:

[Determine the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{d}})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1367383/determine-the-galois-group-of-mathbbq-sqrtab-sqrtd?noredirect=1&lq=1)

We see that the extension is normal, if $a^2-db^2$ is a square. For $(a,b,d)=(2,3,1)$ we obtain our case.

Comment: the answer of Ofir their is correct? and why we need to prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}})$ is normal?

Comment: Why? Because this is your question: $L=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}})$.