# Determination of $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\alpha=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$.

Let $L=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

> Determine $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your attempts? Have you found the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$? And the conjugates of $\alpha$? Did you realize that $L$ is a biquadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: The same question was a few hours ago. I gave already an answer with links - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2519605/normal-extension-of-a-group). Please do not repost the same question twice!

Comment: but here i want to determine the Galoi groupe of the quotient

Comment: This is not true. You wrote:"Determine $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$", i.e., the Galois group of the extension $L/\mathbb{Q}$ (this is not a quotient but rather a field extension).